# Use one line of code to print a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of strings stored in results that I want to print one at a time to look like this:

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
etc.
```

Right now, I have this, which works fine:

```
for line in results:
    print line
```

I am just trying to see if it is possible to condense it into a single line to determine the simplest, shortest solution.

I am able to assign a variable to a list, for example `numbers = [i for i in range(5)]`.
Is it then possible to convert *my* code to something like this?

```
print line for line in results
```

I have tried a couple variations to no avail, and I have exhausted my research on the topic and haven't found anything conclusive. I'm just curious to see what is possible. Thanks!

Comment: `for line in results: print line`. All on a single line. Here you go.

Comment: Of course! Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for line in results: print line
```

Using Python 3.0 print function with list comprehension:

```
from __future__ import print_function

[print(line) for line in results]
```

Comment: Or `map(print, results)`

Answer (score 4):

`print('\n'.join(str(line) for line in results))`

Comment: It's more efficient to create a list comprehension for join.

Comment: Why is it more efficient? I did a couple tests where I ran that code 40000 times, and I found the results quite similar: somewhere between 2 and 4 seconds.

Comment: Python has to create a list from the generator to be able to know how much memory to allocate for the final string. So you have the slight overhead of the generator.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution for printing in single line will be using

**end = " "**

Here is my code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
   print(arr[i])
```

If I use the above code the answer

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

By using the solution below:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
   print(arr[i], end = " ")
```

We get the answer:
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: This is not what was asked. The objective is printing everything coding in just one line.